# Android browser history URI?

Tags: android, uri, android-contentprovider, android-browser

I need to save the last visited webpage by user. 
Evething works fine with my Galaxy S4 (5.0.1) with Chrome Browser.

However, on some phones I got nothing or very mixed results. From what I gathered, the biggest problem is with Browser URI itself. Some phones use Chrome as their main browser, some use something else.

I have three sources:
`content://com.android.chrome.browser/bookmarks`
`content://com.sec.android.app.sbrowser/bookmarks`
`Browser.BOOKMARKS_URI`

So right now I'm working on something like this:

```
    @Override
    public void onChange(boolean selfChange) {
        super.onChange(selfChange);
        h.removeCallbacks(this);
        h.postDelayed(this, 500);
    }

    public void run() {

        String[] proj = new String[] { Browser.BookmarkColumns.TITLE, Browser.BookmarkColumns.URL,Browser.BookmarkColumns.DATE };
        String selection = Browser.BookmarkColumns.BOOKMARK + " = 0"; // 0 = history, 1 = bookmark
        Cursor mCur = null;
        try {
            mCur = contentResolver.query(getURI(), proj, selection, null, null);
            if(mCur != null && mCur.moveToLast()){

                String title = "";
                String url = "";

                title = mCur.getString(mCur.getColumnIndex(Browser.BookmarkColumns.TITLE));
                url = mCur.getString(mCur.getColumnIndex(Browser.BookmarkColumns.URL));

                ...


            }

        } catch (Exception e){

                ...

        } finally {
            if(mCur != null)
                mCur.close();
        }
    }

    private Uri getURI(){
        Uri uri = Uri.parse("content://com.android.chrome.browser/bookmarks");
        return uri;
    }
```

1. Whet is the best way to provide correct URI?
   onChange is triggered as content observer on browsers history.

So user can browse internet on Chrome and I still get history results from ASOP browser. 
When I observe chrome directly, on some phones I get `failed to find provider info`, because there is no chrome installed.

2. What are other "popular" sources to search for browser history? I'd prefer to make this as bulletproof as possible.

Answer (score 3):

try it: (run perfectly in android > 4.0 and 5 or 6.0 ); Anything, create a contentObserver array in FOREACH and add a list and record a different URI for each.

in service android (background):

```
HistoryObserver hObserver;

 public void onCreate() {
   hObserver = new HistoryObserver(new Handler(), this); 
   getApplicationContext().getContentResolver().registerContentObserver(Uri.parse("content://com.android.chrome.browser/history"), true, hObserver);
 }
```

Class historicObserver:

```
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Calendar;

import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.ContentObserver;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.provider.Browser;
import android.util.Log;

public class HistoryObserver extends ContentObserver {

public final String TAG = "HistoryObserver";

Context context;

public HistoryObserver(Handler handler, Context c) {
    super(handler);
    Log.d(TAG, "Creating new HistoryObserver");
    context = c;
}

public HistoryObserver(Context c) {
    super(null);
    Log.d(TAG, "Creating a new HistoryObserver without a Handler");
    context = c;
}

@Override
public boolean deliverSelfNotifications() {
    Log.d(TAG, "delivering self notifications");
    return true;
}

@Override
public void onChange(boolean selfChange) {
    super.onChange(selfChange);
    Log.d(TAG, "onChange without uri: " + selfChange);
    // onChange(selfChange, null);
}

@SuppressLint("NewApi")
public void onChange(boolean selfChange, Uri uri) {
    super.onChange(selfChange, uri);


    Log.d(TAG, "onChange: " + selfChange + "\t " + uri.toString());

    String[] proj = new String[] { Browser.BookmarkColumns.TITLE,
            Browser.BookmarkColumns.URL, Browser.BookmarkColumns.DATE };
    String selection = Browser.BookmarkColumns.BOOKMARK + " = 0"; // 0 =
                                                                    // history,
                                                                    // 1 =
                                                                    // bookmark

    try {
        Thread.sleep(1500);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    Cursor mCursor = context.getContentResolver().query(Browser.BOOKMARKS_URI,
            proj, selection, null, null);
    // this.startManagingCursor(mCursor);
    mCursor.moveToFirst();
    int count = mCursor.getColumnCount();
    String COUNT = String.valueOf(count);
    Log.e("Browser sayac", COUNT);

    String title = "";
    String url = "";
    String date = "";
    if (mCursor.moveToFirst() && mCursor.getCount() > 0) {

        while (mCursor.isAfterLast() == false) {

            title = mCursor.getString(mCursor
                    .getColumnIndex(Browser.BookmarkColumns.TITLE));
            url = mCursor.getString(mCursor
                    .getColumnIndex(Browser.BookmarkColumns.URL));
            date = mCursor.getString(mCursor
                    .getColumnIndex(Browser.BookmarkColumns.DATE));
            Long timestamp = Long.parseLong(date);

            SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(
                    "dd/MM/yyyy/HH:mm");
            Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
            calendar.setTimeInMillis(timestamp);
            String finaldate = dateFormat.format(calendar.getTime());
            String smsDate = finaldate.toString();

            // Log.e("DTE", date);
            Log.e("URL", title);

            Log.e("TARIH", smsDate);
            mCursor.moveToNext();
        }
    }
}
```

}